# Joomla com problemas de segurança no GSC

Tags: segurança, google, algoritmo-de-busca, seo, joomla

Temos um site em Joomla, no Google ele passou a aparecer com não seguro, verificamos no Google problemas de segurança com URLs estranhas.

**Temos visto que o Google encontra problemas com páginas deste tipo:**
site.com.br/2122/whuk16867_/swphtxj/_36_vj.jp.shtml
site.com.br/2885/whuk33625_/swphtxj/_36_vj.jp.shtml
site.com.br/dictionary/sekaidaihyakka/

Apensar de realmente parecer ser um ataque, nós não sabemos como o Google cai nestas páginas, nem conseguimos visualizar.

Na guia do Google Search Console para problemas de segurança vemos que ele considera ser uma "invasão com spam" e que as páginas tem "injeção de URL".

O que já fizemos:

- Atualizamos o Joomla e módulos
- Buscamos estas URLs ou partes delas no banco e arquivos, mas não encontramos nada
- instalamos plugins para customizar as páginas de erros, mas quando tentamos chegar nestas páginas o erro é "Not Found" em vez das páginas customizadas

O que nos parece

- Que apenas o bot vê estes links ou as páginas
- Que a URL dura pouco tempo
- Que isso ocorre ao menos uma vez ao dia
- Não tem relação com os dados no banco

O que acham?

Answer (score -1):

Miguel, se já foi feita a verificação de todos os arquivos do site, buscando por scripts maliciosos, então devemos buscar outras alternativas:

**Verificar indexação**

Por uma busca rápida aqui, de acordo com a url informada, consegui verificar que ainda existem urls indexadas.

Acredito que alguma página extrangeira esteja linkando seu site. Use o *Google Webmaster Tools* para saber que site é este e tomar as medidas cabíveis.

**Remover do índice as páginas falsas**

Use o Webmaster Tools para remover do índice as páginas mencionadas, bem como todo o complemento da url, por ex.: *"/2885/whuk33625_/*"*

**Instalar WAF ( Web Firewall Application )**

O mais recomendado é o  [*RS FIREWALL*.](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-security/rsfirewall.)

Caso não queria usá-lo, no *Joomla Extensions* existem alternativas à ele.

Ele também permite fazer uma varredura no site, em busca de scripts maliciosos.

**Bloquear Ips de fora do país**

Deixe liberado somente os ips internos do Brasil para evitar scans e ataques de outros países. No RS Firewall também tem como liberar/bloquear ips por continente.

**Verifique se o host mantém atualização de serviços**

Veja se o host está com as últimas versões estáveis do PHP, Apache/Nginx, Mysql/MariaDB, dependendo do caso. Também veja se eles mantém o kernel do SO atualizado.

Acredito que com estas medidas você começa a remover o problema e evitar futuras invasões.